# In Android FingerPaint demo how can I erase drawn paths

Tags: paint, android

I've been trying to alter the Android (v3.0 Honeycomb) API Demo FingerPaint (API >= 11) to include a working erase option that removes the last drawn path.

The erase in the API demo doesnt work well, in v3.0 is crashes, in v3.1 is draws a black box while only partially erasing the path (a bug has been raised not sure if it has been resolved in v3.2 [not out for Xoom device in UK]).

My code is as follows:

```
public void eraseLastPath() {
    if (!mPaths.isEmpty()) {
        mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPaths.pop(), mPaint);
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

This somewhat works but leaves an outline of the drawn path on the canvas. e.g.

this:
[image]

is erased to look like this:
[image]

What am I missing? Is there a better way to erase paths?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Joe

Comment: @Lumis I had set mPaint.setAntiAlias(true) which was causing the issue.  If you'd like to answer the question I'll mark it as correct and upvote it so you get the kudos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set mPaint anti-alias on.

Edit:

The proper way to erase a path is to store all strokes into an ArrayList and then remove the unwanted one and redraw everything. The method used in the question is not really deleting a path but more like drawing another colour over it, but then anti-alias would not work the same as with the first colour.

Each path needs to be a member object in a new class "stroke", which also has colour, paint, filters etc stored. In this way all drawing can be restored and it can have infinite undo.

Comment: ..well set anti-alias off. ;)

Comment: I thought it was to do with anti-alias but was not sure if it was on or off that was causing this effect. Wouldn't be easier not to use xfer mode and just change the color of the Path into the background color when erasing? In this case you could keep anti-alias on.

Answer (score 1):

Hold the last drawn `Path`(s) separately (not drawn onto `Bitmap`) for drawing. This allows you to manipulate the `Path`s before committing them to a backing `Bitmap`.

For example:

```
private List<Path> undoablePaths;    

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    for(Path path : undoablePaths){
        canvas.drawPath(path, pathPaint);   
    }
    canvas.drawBitmap(mainBitmap, 0, 0, bitmapPaint);
}

private void undoLast(){
    undoablePaths.remove(undoablePaths.size() - 1);
    invalidate();
}
```

**Note:** The example doesn't allow for multiple colours. You can just extend the `Path` object and hold colour information on it (and set the `Paint` accordingly).

Also, if you are using this with a Honeycomb device, make sure you have hardware acceleration turned on with `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`.

Comment: thanks for the fast response, it's certainly another way of handling the paths drawn and undoing them however Lumis pointed out the anti-alias on my Paint object was the cause of my particular issue.  Thanks again.

Comment: Err that isn't an 'undo'. Think about underlying paths - you will be drawing over those as well!

Comment: I think that is proper way to do it - I would not use a List of Paths as objects but a List of a new class like PaintStroke which would have in it a Path object rather than extending the Path, plus various settings etc and some public methods. This would allow an easy manipulation of Strokes.

Comment: @Lumis - hence the 'note' in my answer! :P

Comment: But in your note you said to extend the Path, which is only required if you want to change or add to its underling methods. This also means that you would need to know how the Path actually works on a lower level ;)

Comment: A Path is a concrete class (not abstract) so it would be okay to extend it. However, it may be better to wrap it up with another class. Different topic!

Comment: Hi Lumis, did you get the solution. I am also working on same problem for FingerPaint example. Can you tell me the solution ?